# SQL for calculating salary contribution by each department

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a simple query using in oracle database that finds the salary contribution by each department.

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  empid NUMBER,
  fname VARCHAR2(20),
  deptid NUMBER,
  salary NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE department (
 deptid NUMBER,
 deptname VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

Inserting data into this table:

```
INSERT INTO department VALUES (1, 'Sales');
INSERT INTO department VALUES (2, 'Accounting');

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (1,' John', 1,100);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (2,' Lisa', 2,200);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (3,' Jerry', 1,300);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (4,' Sara', 1,400);
```

Now to find out the salary contribution in percentage by each department I am using below query:

```
select dept.deptname, sum(emp.salary)/(select sum(emp.salary) from employee emp)*100 as percentge from employee emp, department dept where dept.deptid=emp.deptid group by dept.deptname;
```

Is this efficient way of calculating my output or Is there any alternate way?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a subquery for this.  You can use analytic functions:

```
select dept.deptname,
       100*sum(emp.salary)/(sum(sum(emp.salary)) over ()) as percentage
from employee emp join
     department dept 
     on dept.deptid = emp.deptid 
group by dept.deptname;
```

I also changed the `join` syntax to use ANSI standard joins.

EDIT:

There is not a particular "issue" with using subqueries for this.  A subquery does work.  In general, though, subqueries are harder to optimize than the built-in features in Oracle (and in this case in ANSI SQL).  In this simple case, I don't know if there is a performance difference.

As for analytic functions, they are a very powerful component of SQL and you should learn about them.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon, I am still learning queries, can you please tell me what is the issue in using subquery? I am not aware of analytic functions, so it would be helpful if you can give some details about the query you posted and also if possible can you please suggest where can I learn the analytic queries.

Comment: @user2065083 You can learn about the Analytic Functions in the Oracle Database SQL Language Reference. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select distinct a.*,
  (sum(Salary) over(partition by a.DeptID))/(sum(Salary) over())*100 "Percent"
from department a join employee b on a.deptid=b.deptid
```

Comment: Thanks TechDo, can you please help me in understanding the query that you has given here.

Answer (score 0):

By **with** clause you can calculate sum for all departments once and then use it as parameter. On your example sum value for all departments calculated for each row and this will lead to performance loss.

```
    with t as
    (select sum(salary) as sum_salary from employee)

    select dept.deptname, sum(emp.salary)/ sum_salary * 100 as percentge 
    from employee emp, department dept, t 
    where dept.deptid=emp.deptid group by dept.deptname, sum_salary;
```